# Divs scrolling down but going over the bottom div's

Tags: javascript, css, html, position

I dont know whether I explain the title properly. Sorry for bad english.

I made the sidebar as div:fixed. but when I scroll down I need to stop it after sometime rather than going beyond the other divs.

http://binarix.com/newsite/index.php/training/3-month-close-the-sale-program

Can someone help me

Comment: You'll need to use JS for the effect you want.

Comment: but withou JS we can do the scrolling. but is there anyway I can stop from a specific place

Comment: Nope. CSS can't dynamically watch the window scroll position and change element position properties. If you use jQuery, you can script this in like 15 lines of code. Think $(window).scrollTop() and $(window).scroll(). http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is with JavaScript code, changing the display mode of the div when the user scrolls past a certain point.

[StickyScroll](http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll) may be a useful thing to look at, if you are using jQuery.